# Build custom files w/o 'Custom Tool' in MSVS2012

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, build-process

What I like to do is compile a custom file to generate a C# file. I only need it to compile when its been changed but compiling everytime is ok.

When I looked around I kept finding reference to Custom Tool and found this [pretty good article](http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/developing-custom-tool-aka-single-file-generators-for-visual-studio-2012/). I remember pre2010 I was able to have a build rule for extensions but it looks like that doesn't exist anymore? It allowed me to specify an extension and bin+args to run against when the file changed. Whats the closest thing to that? It looks like it no longer supported which is exactly what I want

Custom Tool requires me to mess around with registry, create a dll and requires VS SDK. Its way overkill for something I done with ease in the past.

How do I have visual studios run my exe to build a custom extension source file without going into overkill like custom tool above? Must work for C# project, C++ projects would be nice but not required.

Comment: Have you looked at [T4 Templates?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: I would not recommend taking Single File Generator route but - as suggested by John - would use T4.